# Invariant means on locally $\sigma$-comapct groups

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, amenability

Let $G$ be a locally compact and $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff group. Is true that $G$ is [amenable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group)? My attempt is to consider a sequence $(K_n)$ of compact subsets of $G$ such that $G=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} K_n$ and for each $n$ define $m_n:L^\infty(G)\to\mathbb{R}$ as
$$ m_n(f) = \frac{1}{\mu(K_n)}\int_{K_n}f\textrm{ d}\mu,$$

where $\mu$ is the Haar measure, and prove that for all ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$, the limit

$$m_{\mathcal{U}}=\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\mathcal{U}-\lim}\ m_n$$

in the weak*-topology of $L^\infty(G)^*$ defines a left-invarian mean on $G$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, any countable group is $\sigma$-compact but not all such groups are amenable, e.g.  the free group on two generators.